# CORS Problem in lumen/laravel with headers set

Tags: laravel, cors, lumen

I'm working on a new lumen project and i'm trying to communicate with it from an angular project.
I've added a middleware to add the following headers for local requests using a middleware:

```
$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
```

But i still have issue with CORS.

```
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/sign-in' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Request URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/sign-in
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I run the project using the php built-in server and never had problem like this before.
I checked if the middleware was executed and there was no problem here, so I don't have any idea. All I found when searching for help was about adding the headers or server configuration, so it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how my middleware looks like and works fine:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'       => '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'      => 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'  => 'true',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age'            => '86400',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'      => 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token,  Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
    ];

    if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')){
        return response()->json(['method' => 'OPTIONS'], 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value) {
        $response->header($key, $value);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Give a try, maybe it helps.

P.S. Be sure to send the request to the correct url.

Comment: It worked for a moment, and a few hours later I have the same error again. I don't understand... (and yes, it's the correct URL)

Comment: @Kalika If it worked it means that everything its ok with this code. My web app is running fine with this middleware. And post all the errors in order that I or someone else can help you!